# SQL OR logic sorting

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have columns for games `PC=1/0`, `XBX=1/0`, `PS4=1/0`.  I'm returning the results based on the check box selected for `PC`, `XBX` and `PS4` and getting the results.

If the platforms checked using `pc=1 OR xbx=1 OR ps4=1`.

I'm using PHP implode like this.

[MySQL query for multiple checkbox values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522587/mysql-query-for-multiple-checkbox-values)

The PHP implode works perfectly but it fails if the all plt.

The Query like

```
SELECT  p1.date_id as rDate,     
        p1.game_name as gameName,         
        p1.release_type as rType,     
        p1.notes as rNotes,     
        on_pc as is_PC,     
        on_xb1 as is_XB1,     
        on_ps4 as is_PS4,     
        ie.[Event Name] as event_name     
FROM dbo.vw_fps_game_list p1     
LEFT JOIN dbo.Industry_Events_db ie ON ie.[Date] = p1.date_id   
WHERE (on_xb1=1 OR on_ps4=1 OR on_xb1)   
ORDER BY on_pc DESC
```

I need to show the results in this order
if all 3 platforms are checked,
 then `where (pc=1 OR xb1=1 OR ps4=1)` needs to be sorted on the top,  then `where (pc =1 OR xb1=1 ) / (pc =1 OR ps4=1)/ (ps4 =1 OR xb1=1 )`,  then `(pc =1) / (xb1=1)/ (ps4=1)`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorting and OR, yuck. Good luck with performance... just saying.

Comment: What do you suggest for better performance?

Comment: If you have good DB design (all fields in WHERE and ORDER are indexed) and you have poor performance.  Then you can do a sub-query using the stuff in WHERE as UNION ALL in place of the or's, then sort it then join on the outer part with the other tables and pull the data, so It's much more complex, likely 2 sub-queries.  But it will be 2 to 5 times as fast.  I can post an example as an answer.

Comment: What is this `OR on_xb1)` AND what tables are the `on_*` stuff in?  I'll need to know that if you want me to do an example of what I said above.  I've used that in the past and reduced a query from 12 seconds down to just under 1 second ( searching on about 800k rows )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last paragraph, with the following script you could achieve what you are trying.

```
   SELECT p1.date_id       as rDate
        , p1.game_name     as gameName
        , p1.release_type  as rType
        , p1.notes         as rNotes
        , on_pc            as is_PC
        , on_xb1           as is_XB1
        , on_ps4           as is_PS4
        , ie.[Event Name]  as event_name
     FROM dbo.vw_fps_game_list p1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Industry_Events_db ie
       ON ie.[Date] = p1.date_id
    WHERE (on_xb1=1 or on_ps4=1 or on_xb1)
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN      on_pc  = 1
                     AND on_ps4 = 1
                     AND on_xb1 = 1                     THEN 1
               WHEN     (on_pc  = 1 AND on_xb1 = 1)
                     OR (on_pc  = 1 AND on_ps4 = 1)
                     OR (on_ps4 = 1 AND on_xb1 = 1)     THEN 2
               WHEN     (on_pc  = 1)
                     OR (on_xb1 = 1)
                     OR (on_ps4 = 1)                    THEN 3
               ELSE 4
           END ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case for set your order value

```
  SELECT 
    p1.date_id as rDate
    , p1.game_name as gameName
    , p1.release_type as rType
    , p1.notes as rNotes
    , on_pc as is_PC
    , on_xb1 as is_XB1
    , on_ps4 as is_PS4
    , ie.[Event Name] as event_name     
    , case when on_pc = 1 and on_xb1 = 1 and on_ps4 = 1 then 0
           when on_pc_= 1 and on_xb1 = 1 and on_ps4 = 0 then 1
           when on_pc_= 1 and on_xb1 = 0 and on_ps4 = 0 then 2
               ELSE 3
       END as my_order
  FROM dbo.vw_fps_game_list p1     
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Industry_Events_db ie on ie.[Date] = p1.date_id   
  WHERE (on_xb1=1 or on_ps4=1 or on_xb1)   
  ORDER BY my_order
```